# Disable background activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, transparency

I currently have an activity that displays a gridView. When a specific button is pressed I create a new fragment that has a transparent content view so that it overlays the activity gridView, so basically you see the content of the new fragment while still vaguely seeing the gridView in die background. The problem I have is that the background view (the gridView) is still active and the user is able to press buttons "through" the fragment view and onto the gridView, if this makes sense. How can I disable the background view/activity (gridView) so the user cannot activate any of the content hosted by it? I was thinking I could do something along the following lines, but it seems very inefficient and hackish:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
    for (int i = 0;i<vg.getChildCount();i++) {
        enableViews(vg.getChildAt(i), enabled);
    }
```

Is there any other solution or approach I could take?

I set my transparency for the entire fragments view via style like this:

```
<style name="Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">#e6000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you downvote the question could you please be so kind as to provide an explanation so that other people can find some use out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this question got down voted as I feel it was a legitimate question, perhaps my phrasing was bad or something. Anyways, I've found a solution incase anyone else ever runs into a similar situation. All you need to do is to set the overlay screens root layout clickable property to true: (in this particular case the fragments main layout)

```
android:clickable="true"
```